# Why can't I make a frozeset of a list?

Tags: python

When I try the code below:

```
frozenset([[]])
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "-----.-----.py", line 1, in <module>
    frozenset([[]]) TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Why can't I do this?

Answer (score 4):

In Python, [the elements of set must be hashable](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset). As the [Python docs explain](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-hashable):

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a **hash**() method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an **eq**() method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.

This is because the set needs to be able to efficiently perform set operations and quickly determine if an item is in the set or not (by comparing hash values). Since list are mutable and not hashable, then they can't be put in a set.

In your code, if you were to say `frozenset([])` then that would be fine. In this case, you are creating a `frozenset` of the items in `[]` which should all be hashable (since there aren't any items in the list, then the hashable-ness is not a problem). But when you say `frozenset([[]])`, then Python tries to create a `frozenset` of all the items in the outer list; but the first item in the outer list is another list (`[]`) which is not hashable; so you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Because `lists` are `mutable` and their values can change.

You need `immutable` objects like strings or tuples etc.

If the value of an object changes it's hash value would also change.

[object values and types](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)

Brandon Rhodes gives a very good explanation on how  hashing works in Python in relation to dictionaries [the mighty dictionary](http://pyvideo.org/video/276/the-mighty-dictionary-55)